# Object grouping with linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects that I want to transform into another list of objects.

The first object looks like this:

```
    private class ObjectOne
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Item{ get; set; }
    }
```

And another like this

```
public class ObjectTwo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to write a linq query or lambda expression that can convert a list of ObjectOne data into a list of ObjectTwo data.  Each item in the list of ObjectTwo will contain a distinct name from ObjectOne along will an enumeration of all the items associated with that name.

For example the following list of ObjectOne data

```
"Name One", "Item One"
"Name One", "Item Two"
"Name Two", "Item Three"
```

would produce the following ObjectTwo list:

```
"Name One", {"Item One", "Item Two"}
"Name Two", {"Item Three"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the GroupBy Linq operator. Then for each grouping, select the Key (the one you used to group it with), and convert the items of each group into a List.

```
var oneList = new List<ObjectOne>
              {
                new ObjectOne {Name = "Name One", Item = "Item One"},
                new ObjectOne {Name = "Name One", Item = "Item Two"},
                new ObjectOne {Name = "Name Two", Item = "Item Three"}
              };

var twoList= oneList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select (x => new ObjectTwo 
                                   {
                                      Name = x.Key, 
                                      Items = x.Select(t => t.Item)
                                   });
```

Comment: +1 for *not* using query comprehension syntax. Would have been +2 if you would just write "n =>" instead of "one =>" :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the `group by` LINQ operator:

```
var obj2List =
    from o in list
    group o by o.Name into g
    select new ObjectTwo() {Name = g.Key, Items = g.Select(x => x.Item)};
```